# Why does PNotify conflict with sessions?

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, prototypejs, pnotify

I have written a session handler which regenerates the session on every page load.

This works perfectly, until I include the [library for PNotify](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella/tree/master/production/js/notify). After some troubleshooting, I can only guess that this is writing a cookie or something to the browser, but I am unable to locate any 'cookie' or 'session' type commands in the script.

Where is it writing data to the browser which is inherently causing this issue -  and/or  -  how do I adjust this so that it works without breaking sessions?

I would supply the session code, however it is irrelevant given the problem is not in the server code, but more the fact that PNotify is overwriting something client side (presumably the session cookie), making it incompatible with regenerated sessions.

Comment: Resolved. Turns out I had the path wrong for the file, which was causing the session to destroy itself.